# Add preliminary elements to the ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

Assume I have finished two sections of my book so far, yet I want to display my preliminary ToC with all parts and chapters (but with no page number) as a preview like this:

```
I  First Part              1

1  First Chapter           3
   1.1  First Section .... 3
   1.2  Second Section ... 5
   1.3  Third Section ....
2  Second Chapter
   2.1  First Section ....
   2.2  Second Section ...
   2.3  Third Section ....

II Second Part

3  Third Chapter
   1.1  First Section ....
   1.2  Second Section ...
   1.3  Third Section ....
4  Fourth Chapter
   2.1  First Section ....
   2.2  Second Section ...
   2.3  Third Section ....
```

How can I include these pseudo-parts/chapters/sections etc. without having empty parts/chapters/sections in the document.

Comment: Well, you could use `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{theverysophisticatedtitle}` etc, but this is tedious and won't update the corresponding numbers. Should the titles be 'correct' already or are dummy titles sufficient?

Comment: I would like to use the proper names to have a draft of the final ToC.

Comment: I would nevertheless suggest a cleaner solution with `empty` chapters etc, doing nothing, perhaps with a boolean state variable

Comment: Are you referring to a possibility of trailing empty chapters etc which can be omitted from the final output - at least as the content is concerned? I was actually thinking about using `\includepdf` to just grab the first part - i wasn't sure though whether `hyperref` links would break or not.

Comment: No, hacking the structure command codes to do basically nothing (apart from adding a toc entry) if a certain boolean state is true or false. You could place the change of the state to that position in your document which divides it to written/unwritten content ... Perhaps I have some time this evening

Comment: Thank you very much though on your attempts so far!

Comment: See the updated version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** See the `GhostChapters` version at the bottom

The preliminary entries can be added by faking `\addtocontents` and omitting the 2nd argument to the original `\contentsline{}` command, thus removing the page number.

In lack of a MWE this works for `book`, `scrbook` and `memoir` classes so far only.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%

\newcommand{\addfakecontent}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{#1}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{#1}{\csuse{the#1}\hspace{1em}#2}{}}
}%


\AtEndDocument{%

\addfakecontent{part}{The next to final part}
\addfakecontent{chapter}{Some chapter of another part}%
\addfakecontent{chapter}{Even another chapter of another part}%


\addfakecontent{part}{The final part}
\addfakecontent{chapter}{Some chapter of the final part}
\addfakecontent{section}{A section of a final part}



}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First}

\chapter{Some chapter content}

\blindtext



\end{document}
```

[image]

### Ghostchapter - version

This version uses the concept of `ghost` chapters (i.e. \parts, \chapters etc.) By using `\EnableGhostChapters` at 'any' arbitrary position in the document the following structure commands are disabled, but add an entry to `ToC`. It works for `scrbook`, `memoir` down to `subparagraph`, and up to `subsubsection` for `book` class -- I did not figure out why it fails for `paragraph` and `subparagraph` for the book class... (weird definition?)

The ghost chapters are displayed with `darkgray` color in the ToC.

Use `\DisableGhostChapters` to switch back to normal behaviour.

The macros `\EnablePagesInToc` and `\DisablePagesInToc` enable/disable the display of the page number in the ToC

Note: Although I used `\patchcmd` ... it's not a patch, it's a hack ;-)

It does not work correctly for `\include{}` but with `\input{}`

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%


\newcommand{\preliminarycontentscolor}{darkgray}

\newbool{UsePagesInToc}  


\newbool{GhostChapters}



\newcommand{\EnablePagesInToc}{%
\clearpage
\setbool{UsePagesInToc}{true}%
}%

\newcommand{\DisablePagesInToc}{%
\setbool{UsePagesInToc}{false}%
}%


\newcommand{\EnableGhostChapters}{%
\DisablePagesInToc%
\setbool{GhostChapters}{true}%
}%


\newcommand{\DisableGhostChapters}{%
\EnablePagesInToc%
\setbool{GhostChapters}{false}%
}%




\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\makeatletter





\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \ifbool{UsePagesInToc}{%
    \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\thepage}}%
  }{%
    \addtocontents{#1}{\begingroup\color{\preliminarycontentscolor}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{}}\endgroup}
  }%
}%


\makeatletter

\patchcmd{\@part}{%
  \markboth{}{}%
  {\centering
    \interlinepenalty \@M
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart%
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
   \@endpart%
 }{%
  \ifbool{GhostChapters}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{%
  \markboth{}{}%
  {\centering
    \interlinepenalty \@M
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart%
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
   \@endpart%
  }%
}{\typeout{part structure successfully patched}}{\typeout{part structure patching failed}}


\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\chaptermark{#1}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \if@twocolumn
  \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
  \else
  \@makechapterhead{#2}%
  \@afterheading
  \fi}{% Patch
  \ifbool{GhostChapters}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{%
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
    \else
    \@makechapterhead{#2}%
    \@afterheading
    \fi}
}{\typeout{chapter structure successfully patched}}{\typeout{chapter structure patching failed}}


\patchcmd{\@sect}{%  
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}{%
  \ifbool{GhostChapters}{%
    \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
      \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7}
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
          \fi
          #7}}%
    \fi%
    \@xsect{#5}%
  }{%
    \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
    #6{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
      \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
      \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7}%
    \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
        \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
    \fi
  \@xsect{#5}
}%
}{\typeout{section structures successfully patched}}{\typeout{section structures patching failed}}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DisableGhostChapters%
  \EnablePagesInToc%
}%

\AtEndDocument{%
\phantom{some output}
}%

\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\DisableGhostChapters
\tableofcontents



\part{First}

\chapter{First of first part}

\section{First section of first chapter}

\subsection{First subsection}

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\paragraph{First paragraph}

\subparagraph{First subparagraph}

\blindtext

\chapter{Second chapter}



\EnableGhostChapters

\part{OtherOne}



\chapter{New Chapter}

\section{Section of another chapter}%


\chapter{Another chapter}

\chapter{Yet another chapter of another part}

\section{First section of another chapter}

\subsection{First subsection}

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\paragraph{First paragraph}

\subparagraph{First subparagraph}


\EnablePagesInToc
\DisableGhostChapters

\chapter{You will see me!}

\part{And some visible part}

\EnableGhostChapters%
\DisablePagesInToc%
\chapter{With an invisible chapter}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with my current source files, yet with your MWE it does - I will have to find out what's interfering, thank you so far. Meanwhile, do you know how to specifically remove the page numbers from the fake content? Otherwise I would have to live with it having them.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: I am working to remove them... I know, that there is a caveat... It would be nice to know which class and packages you are using

Comment: Actually I fixed the issue as I was using `input` rather than `include` for my chapters and your code is now working as intended. Just the page numbers and we're good to go! Concerning packages I am just using `book` with the usual ams packages, etoolbox, some tikz packages, but nothing too fancy so far (except fancyhdr ;-) ).

Comment: I was actually wrong! When using `\include{Chapter1}` your code does not work if all structural elements are in the second file. Adding a `\chapter{Foo}` after the include yields the expected result with the fake entries. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: I just tested it with some `\include{...}` and `\input{...}` -- it works

Comment: Then I will have to dive through all used packages and disable one-by-one. Nevertheless I am receiving a new error with your newest version of the snippet: `Argument of \contentsline has an extra }` for the line `\contentsline{chapter}{2\hspace {1em}Some chapter of another part}{}`.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: Delete the `.toc` and the `.aux` files before introducing `\addfakecontents`...

Comment: Your newest Ghost-version works - and I found out what the issue with the `\contentsline` command was - `hyperref` changes the function such that it needs five and not three arguments. Thanks for this second approch which is much better!

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: I'll try to correct for `hyperref` as well